How to track/monitor the GCP Security Center Exports to BigQuery?
I enabled GCP Security Command Center (SCC) and created an export for the findings in the GCP SCC to be pushed into BigQuery dataset. Everything works as I want, however one main problem is that I can not track the status of exports. Google offers a solution for continuous exports and I applied it, yet I still need to check the status for unpredicted downtimes.
Here is the command I used to create export:
gcloud scc bqexports create scc-bq-cont-export --dataset=projects/$PROJECT_ID/datasets/dataset_name --project=$PROJECT_NAME 
For official documentation of Google, Refer to this link, Task 2
So my question is that, is there a built-in tool for that in Google Cloud? If yes, that would be great because I do not want to build the monitoring on exports, since it will rely on me. But if the answer is no, I like to get ideas because I am not sure what to do next.
